# How to make a custom user account without using email or phone number in firebase android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Let's say I want to make a school app. The school has 100 students. And now I want to make an account for each student (100 accounts) using **id** as username and a custom password. Students can't change the password, it's static. Should I use the Firebase Authentication? If so, how can I do that? This is the json example:

```
{
  "users": {
    "246001": {
      "id": "246001",
      "name": "Anam Stanley",
      "password": "111"
    },
    "246002": {
      "id": "246002",
      "name": "Bella Preston",
      "password": "112"
    },
    "246003": {
      "id": "246003",
      "name": "Killian Serrano",
      "password": "113"
    },
    "246004": {
      "id": "246004",
      "name": "Madelaine Dickinson",
      "password": "114"
    },
    "246005": {
      "id": "246005",
      "name": "Maximus Ramirez",
      "password": "115"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So you want to implement your own authentication mechanism? Why not letting the user sign-in using Firebase Authentication?

Comment: Yes. But I can't let the users register their account by themselves, because the data might not be consistence. Admin will take control of all account. Other than that, sometimes people might be change/forget their email. If I can make it, users don't have to update their data in database when the they lost their email or phone number.

Comment: Firebase offers password resets and if you use another authentication method, that's offered as well. Users continually loose login info so offering some automated process to handle that instead of having the admin do it would be the way to go.

Comment: If I let the users register account by themselves, maybe half of them will do it. Since this is a school app, I want all students have their account. For example, I want to use those students account for mid end exams. So the privacy of each account doesn't really matter

Comment: I think, maybe I can use firebase real time database to make something like, fake login. Will it work? Maybe it wouldn't. I wonder if there is a way to do it in firebase authentication.

Comment: You can very easily create user accounts from the Firebase Console - I wasn't really referring to the registration process, I was more suggesting having an automated process to maintain the account, like a password reset or account recovery option, which you can also do with Firebase Authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to manage users creation (or import) you need to use [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users)